# Issues with zipping files in Java

Tags: java, zip

I am currently trying to zip all files within a directory.

The zip file is being created and the files are being processed - but for some reason the files are not appearing within the zip file.

The code being used to complete this task is as follows:

```
public class FileZipper {

   public void zipDir( String dir, String zipFileName ) {
        try{
            File dirObj = new File(dir);
            ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(zipFileName));
            Logger.info("Creating : " + zipFileName);
            addDir(dirObj, out);
            out.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            Logger.error( e, "Error zipping directory" );
        }
  }

  private void addDir(File dirObj, ZipOutputStream out) throws IOException {
      File[] files;
      if( !dirObj.isDirectory() ){
          files = new File[] { dirObj };
      }
      else{
          files = dirObj.listFiles();
      }
      byte[] tmpBuf = new byte[1024];

      for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
          if (files[i].isDirectory()) {
              addDir(files[i], out);
              continue;
          }
          FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(files[i].getAbsolutePath());
          Logger.info(" Adding: " + files[i].getAbsolutePath());
          out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(files[i].getAbsolutePath()));
          int len;
          while ((len = in.read(tmpBuf)) > 0) {
              out.write(tmpBuf, 0, len);
          }
          out.closeEntry();
          in.close();
      }
  }
}
```

When reviewing the logging information, the files within the directories are being found and processed, but the created zip file contains no data.

Any help with this issues will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: please someone retag this, zipcode seems completely unrelated to me

Comment: My apologies Riccardo - being British (and slightly naive), I had jumped to the conclusion that zipcode was code associated with zipping files - not somewhere you want to send your mail.

Comment: no problem, I had to use a comment just because I don't have enough reputation to retag, otherwise I would have done it myself "silently" :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from the fact that adding the file by its absolute path is probably not what you want, this code works just fine for me.

Comment: Thanks for checking over my code Joachim. I am also getting an error message from my OS that the compressed folder is invalid so I might have to make the assumption that it is my computer that is blocking the files from being written.

Comment: When I used `.` (a.k.a the current directory) as the starting point the ZIP file contained paths such as `/some/directory/./other/stuff.txt`. Maybe your OS chokes on that. Try the ZIP utility of your choice (WinZIP, 7Zip, WinRAR, ...)

Comment: Thanks for all your help Joachim. The problem lay within the absolute paths - when I changed these to relative, the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Hy,
Give a set of files name to this function, and a zip name.
It should work.

```
private void zipFiles (ArrayList<String> listWithFiles, String zipName) {

        try {

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

            // create object of FileOutputStream
            FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(zipName);

            // create object of ZipOutputStream from FileOutputStream
            ZipOutputStream zout = new ZipOutputStream(fout);

            for (String currentFile : listWithFiles) {

                // create object of FileInputStream for source file
                FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(currentFile);

                // add files to ZIP
                zout.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(currentFile ));

                // write file content
                int length;

                while ((length = fin.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    zout.write(buffer, 0, length);
                }

                zout.closeEntry();

                // close the InputStream
                fin.close();
            }

            // close the ZipOutputStream
            zout.close();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("IOException :" + ioe);
        }
    }
```

All good to you,
dAN

Comment: Hi dAn. Thanks for your answer. I think the problem may be an issue with my OS and not with my code. But thank you for your help.